# Header will depend on the change of the operation name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables in which are banking operations and other tables with the amount of operations.

```
Operation Id | name operation 
-------------+----------------
0            | transfer 
1            | registration
2            | BLIK
```

```
Operation Id | amount 
-------------+--------
0            | 15,000 
1            | 53,000 
2            | 200 
E.t.c
```

I was supposed to write a query that shows the names of the operations in the form of a column together with the amount. Well, I wrote something like this:

```
Select 
    case id_operacji 
       when 0 then amount 
    end as 'transfer', 
    case id_operacji 
       when 1 then amount 
    end as 'registration ', 
    case operation id 
       when 2 then amount of operation 
    end as 'BLIK' 
from ...
```

In response to the above solution I received information that the main problem is to check that the header will depend on the change of the operation name. Could someone help me how to do it?

Comment: `as 'transfer'` is invalid SQL to begin with.

Comment: This is example. I came up with it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you are looking for JOIN between the two tables:

```
select a.amount, o.name_operation
from operations o 
  join amounts a on o.operation_id = a.operation_id;
```

I had to guess the table and column names as you did not disclose the real table structures.